# Strange bug. AS3 button

Tags: actionscript-3, button

Strange bug with every my button on stage.

When mouse over to my button - button go to frame 2.
When mouse click to button - button first go to frame 1, after to frame 3.

Button have right, full bounding box. My .fla document not have code. Just one button on stage. Previously, I had no such problem. It appears a few months ago ...

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your code for proof, but this is probably because of a bad event listener.

Check to make sure you're not listening for a MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER. Listen for a MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK to handle your function properly.

Comment: May be in new version FlashPlayer canceled simple button ?
And need do it as MovieClip ? And switch it manually.

Comment: Try remaking it with code instead. http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=28

Make sure you are compiling it with the latest version of Flash Player.

Comment: Thanks. But I used - F8 - Create symbol - type(Button). I not use CODE.
Do you understand me?

Comment: Yes, but if you created a button using f8 you're going to need to program it first. Otherwise it will just sit. You need code to tell it to do something. Otherwise it's just another property on the stage.